# Can we say that space without electric field is of 0 potential?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-fields, potential, voltage

Can we say that a given point in space, without any charges nearby, has *no* electric field, and thus the electric potential in this point is 0?

Answer (score 0):

Such a domain has a constant potential which you can choose as your reference and set to zero. However physically it makes sense to set the potential to zero at infinite distance from any charge. The electrodynamics is not affected by your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Electric field strength is calculated as:

$$E=k\frac Q{r^2}, $$

where $Q$ is the source (the charge that creates the electric field). By "no nearby charges" you probably mean *infinitely far away* from any source charge. Which indeed does correspond to no electric field, $E=0$.

Whether this corresponds to an electric potential of $U_e=0$ depends on where you choose to define the zero-reference. It is often defined as infinitely far away from a source charge, in which case you are correct in your scenario.

Comment: OP asked about the potential though.

Comment: @Steeven, But in reality it won't be correct to just choose a point and say: "this point has 0 potential" - since it's under the influence of some electric field - it has potential. Isn't it?

Comment: @YoavKlein It *is* fine to pick any arbitrary zero-point you want in your scenario. Because only the difference between potentials matter. Just think of gravity: you can define your zero-reference to be the ground so that an object on a shelf is associated with potential energy. But what if there is a hole in the ground? Then you could define the zero-point to be the bottom of the hole instead, in which case *more* potential energy is associated with the object. This doesn't change the math in how much energy that is converted from potential into kinetic when it falls to the ground.